# Как создать инсталляционный пакет (дистрибутив) для разработанного приложения WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, project, setup

Здравствуйте. У меня разработано приложение WPF MVVM с использованием Prism 6.2. Приложение многомодульное. Я также использовал при его разработке контролы от Telerik. Кроме этого, приложение работает с MS SQL Server 2014 (тот, который свободно распространяется Microsoft). Разрабатывал на VisualStudio 2015 Professional (русифицированная). Сейчас мне нужно создать инсталляционный пакет для установки своего приложения на копьютеры пользователей. Если я правильно понимаю, мне нужно создать SetUp project. Никогда раньше я этим не занимался. С чего начать ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться встроенной в VS утилитой ClickOnce: клик правой по названию проекта и выбрать пункт Publish (видимо в русской версии Опубликовать). Но это самый простой вариант, хотя вполне действенный, но для простых проектов.

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что мой проект простой. Что можно использовать из мощных средств создания дистрибутивов? Пускай даже платных.

Comment: [Другой вариант WiX](https://habrahabr.ru/post/68616/)