# Создание инсталлятора для WPF приложения, работающего с локальной БД на SqlServer'е

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, sqlite

**Задача**: Необходимо создать инсталлятор для WPF приложения, которое взаимодействует с локальной базой данных на Sql Server'e.

**Дано**: База данных, которая лежит на сервере, в который я вхожу следующим образом - `имя_компьютера\SQLEXPRESS`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и приложение, которое к ней подключается (точнее имеющее такую строку подключения):

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString"
             connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ChessTrainerDB;Integrated Security=True"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

На данный момент, чтобы установить приложение к себе на компьютер пользователю необходимо:

```
1.Скачать проект с гитхаба.
2.Восстановить с помощью дампа базу данных в SQL Server.
3.Запустить .exe файл и пользоваться программой.
```

**Найти**: Я же хочу сделать установщик для приложения, чтобы пользователь просто установил через exe'шник приложение и пользовался им.

После гугления и поиска по ruSO я нашел следующее - https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread1337712.html и [Как создать инсталляционный пакет (дистрибутив) для разработанного приложения WPF?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/589822/483580) . По первой ссылке точно такой же вопрос как у меня, но там нет нормального ответа на вопрос (предлагается сделать через субд access), по второй же ссылке, как я понял, способ подходит только для приложения без БД (возможно я неправильно понял?).

**Решение**: Итак, какие именно я вижу пути для решения? Их два:

1 - Есть способ в инсталятор запихнуть базу данных и сделать так, чтобы она разворачивалась на компьютере пользователя при установке (но я этот способ просто не нашел)

2 - Либо использовать не SqlServer, а создать базу в SqlLite и уже с SqlLite делать инсталлятор (никогда не работал с SqlLite, прошу скинуть ссылки на какие-то материалы по созданию инсталлятора с SqlLite + по переносу базы данных с SqlServer'а в SqlLite)

Конечно можно было бы сделать не локальный сервер, но этот вариант, к сожалению, мне не подходит.

UPD: Попробовал сделать установщик с помощью ClickOnce и запустил его на виртуалке, приложение открывается, но как только выполнение доходит до взаимодействия с бд (авторизация в системе) приложение вылетает.

Answer (score 0):

Сразу уточню. Что я только добрался до внедрения базы данных, и столкнулся с тем же вопросом. Не успел полноценно протестировать данное решение. И тем более сделать на его основе свой установщик. Есть такой инструмент как "Wix" он создает инсталятор .msi https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/. Сам по себе он сложен в освоении, использует XML синтаксис. На его основе есть WixSharp https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp. Позволяет использовать синтаксис C# напрямую.

Порядок примерно такой:

- Устанавливаешь сам Wix
- Шаблоны WixSharp для Visual Studio https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlegShilo.WixSharpProjectTemplates
  В них присутствует шаблон "WixSharp Managed Setup - Custom WPF UI"

Сборка проекта приводит к создаению установочного пакета .msi. (почти код из шаблона)

```
            var project = new ManagedProject("SSHF", new Dir(@"%ProgramFiles%\My Company\My Product", Files.FromBuildDir("")));

            project.GUID = new Guid("524EE9BC-83E6-4F0D-917E-6A4C69A4DDD4");

            project.ManagedUI = ManagedUI.DefaultWpf; // all stock UI dialogs

            //custom set of UI WPF dialogs
            project.ManagedUI = new ManagedUI();

            project.ManagedUI.InstallDialogs.Add<WixSharp_Setup1.WelcomeDialog>()
                                            .Add<WixSharp_Setup1.LicenceDialog>()
                                            .Add<WixSharp_Setup1.FeaturesDialog>()
                                            .Add<WixSharp_Setup1.InstallDirDialog>()
                                            .Add<WixSharp_Setup1.ProgressDialog>()
                                            .Add<WixSharp_Setup1.ExitDialog>();

            project.ManagedUI.ModifyDialogs.Add<WixSharp_Setup1.MaintenanceTypeDialog>()
                                           .Add<WixSharp_Setup1.FeaturesDialog>()
                                           .Add<WixSharp_Setup1.ProgressDialog>()
                                           .Add<WixSharp_Setup1.ExitDialog>();

            project.SourceBaseDir = @"C:\Work\Studio\SSHF\Base\SSHF\bin\Release\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\publish\win-x64";
            project.OutDir = @"D:\Новая папка\";

            project.BuildMsi();
```

Потенциально должно работать.